# What modern, nonspecialist translations of Boethius, "The Consolation of Philosophy", are available?

Tags: reference-request, translation

I'm presently reading a PG ebook of [The Consolation of Philosophy](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/14328/14328-h/14328-h.htm) and realizing it is great for me to read but the translation is hard reading to offer non-philosophers / non-scholars who visit my website.

What translations are available that are, without loss of faithfulness, easier for a 2018 reader to understand?

Comment: Mine from my Classics courses was https://www.amazon.com/Consolation-Philosophy-Penguin-Classics/dp/0140447806  It is an old standard and so is now cheap.

Comment: @jobermark Thanks for the added resource! At a glance, the reviews make Watts look more similar than different from the PG's H.R. James translation. By comparison with both of them, David Slavitt seems like a philosophical equivalent to *The Message*, of which it is said that someone came to Eugene Peterson and asked, "Are you the person who wrote the Bible?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Boethius, *The Consolation of Philosophy*, tr. David R. Slavitt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674048350).

I've just barely glanced inside, but it reads like a fresh composition; the second paragraph on the back of the book reads, "Slavitt presents the reader with Boethius brought to vibrant, vigorous life, to a degree that makes all previous English versions seem pedantic and irrelevant..."

Now of course there must be some sort of flaws; I haven't read it and it may have the flaws that adherents of literal translation complain infest free translation (and it might in fact not be a free translation). However, the quick glance and the quotes chosen for critical acclaim do suggest that readability is a priority.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've posted the project that motivated my question: [The Consolation of Theology](https://cjshayward.com/consolation/), now included in [The Best of Jonathan's Corner](https://bestof.jonathanscorner.com).